# Issue: Using TPU with OpenNMT-tf

Tags: tensorflow, tpu, opennmt

I am trying to use free Google Colab TPU with [OpenNMT-tf](https://opennmt.net/), it is an open source ecosystem for neural machine translation and neural sequence learning built on top of Tensorflow.
TPU is not implemented yet, so I am trying to do that. I have created a Google cloud bucket, it was able to see it, and create an object in the bucket.
But the training doesn't follow up, it just halts. I get these messages on the terminal, maybe someone can shed some light no this:

> 2020-07-20 08:09:30.121886: I tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/google_auth_provider.cc:180] Attempting an empty bearer token since no token was retrieved from files, and GCE metadata check was skipped.

The whole process can be easily reproduced, also the full output is available in this Google Colab [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13M3SntDXdxuIPa2p6Vp-q9ndnz4y8oC1?usp=sharing)